# Not getting desired output while doing calculation in sql query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one query result as the following format.

```
Price      Quarter  
 80          Q1      
 40          Q2
```

I need to calculate %Value and need to display 'NA' for Q1 and 2 needs to display for Q2

Desired Result is

```
Price      Quarter  %Value
 80          Q1      NA
 40          Q2      2=(80/40)
```

How will I get the desired result?

Comment: If you are on sql 2012 or greater you can use LEAD/LAG. If not, you can use a recursive cte.

Comment: Add Q3 and Q4 rows too, to make things clearer.

Comment: Add table structure and example data. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: use `ctrl-K` or add 4 spaces to format as code

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Your results are very specific.  The following might be what you want:

```
select price, quarter,
       (case when quarter = 'Q1' then NULL
             else value * 1.0 / sum(value) over ()
        end) as col
from q;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any question of the form *compute function of values in two adjacent rows* (in some order) is answered by joining the table to itself, where the join is based on the "previous" value.  See my [running totals](http://www.schemamania.org/sql/#running.totals) example for an explanation.

Your code will look something like this.  The data you provide isn't sufficient to give a complete answer (no year, no identifying key) but I hope this will get you started.

```
select Q.price, Q.quarter, Q.value/P.value as '%value'
from (
     select a.quarter, a.value, max(b.quarter) as prior
     from T as a left join T as b
     on a.quarter > b.quarter
     group by a.price, a.quarter
) as Q
join T as P -- prior
on Q.prior = P.quarter
```